# Responsive UI in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to create responsive UI or design in React Native like View (Horizontal and Portrait mode), Fonts size etc...

And not change any design or UI in any devices it is same in all devices.

I refer many material but i am not satisfied that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For responsive UI you can use react-native-responsive-screen and have the style designed considering the percentage of width and height

For responsive fontsize you can use react-native-responsive-fontsize and have a separate component as fonts.js and use it throughout the app.

fonts.js Component can be as below

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { RFPercentage } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";

export default fonts={
fontSmall: Platform.OS==='android'?  RFPercentage(1.8): RFPercentage(1.5),
fontMedium:  RFPercentage(1.8),
fontEntry:RFPercentage(2.0),
fontHeader:RFPercentage(2.1),
fontTV:RFPercentage(2.2),
fontNormal:RFPercentage(2.5),
fontLargeExtra:RFPercentage(2.7),
fontLarge:RFPercentage(3.0),
fontXLarge:RFPercentage(3.5),
fontXXLarge:RFPercentage(4.0),
fontXXLarge:RFPercentage(4.5),
};
```

The fonts component and the resposive UI in your components can be used as below:

```
import fonts from './fonts';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
viewStyle: {
width: wp('20%'),
marginTop: hp(‘4%’),
height: hp('4.5%'),
fontSize: fonts.fontSmall,
},

});
```

Comment: react-native-responsive-screen is also give the responsive fontSize like fontSize: hp('5%'). So my question is also use fontSize of react-native-responsive-screen?

Comment: react-native-responsive-fontsize also internally calculates the percentage based on const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");.  Yes you can use the same react-native-responsive-screen for font size as hp('5%')